# Bound for the difference of two specific functions

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for a bound to the following equation, so that the sine terms are like together.

$|e^{-at}\sin(bt)-e^{-ct}\sin(dt)|^{p},$

where a,b,c,d and t $\geq 0$ and $1\leq p< \infty$.

Thank you a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?
\begin{align*}
|e^{-at}\sin(bt)-e^{-ct}\sin(dt)|^{p}&\leq (|e^{-at}\sin(bt)| + |e^{-ct}\sin(dt)|)^p\\
&\leq (1 + 1)^p\\
&\leq 2^p
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for a bound where the sine terms are "separated from the rest".